# Can't send List to Postman

Tags: c#, rest, postman

I need to send `List` to Postman. This is how I am doing it:

Postman:

```
{
    "CategoryId": "2139",
    "ListId": "1",
    "ProductsToCompare": [0, 1]
}
```

Request:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProductToComparsionList([FromBody] ProductComparsionVM comparsion)
{
    return Json(await _productRepo.AddProductToComparsionList(comparsion.ProductsToCompare.Select(z => z.ProductId).ToList(), comparsion.CategoryId, comparsion.ListId));
}
```

[image]

It returns null. What I am doing wrong?

**Edit 1**

```
public async Task<ProductComparsionVM> AddProductToComparsionList(List<int> productIds, int categoryId, int? listId)
        {
            if (productIds == null)
                return null;

            var comparsionList = await _dbContext.ProductsComparsion
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(z => z.ProductsToCompare)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.Id.Equals(listId));

            Guid sessionId = default;
            Guid.TryParse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Id, out sessionId);

            foreach(var productId in productIds)
            {
                if (comparsionList == null)
                {
                    var products = _dbContext.Products.Include(z => z.ProductCategories);

                    comparsionList = new ProductComparsion();
                    comparsionList.CategoryId = products.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == productId).ProductCategories.FirstOrDefault().CategoryId;
                    comparsionList.SessionId = sessionId;
                    comparsionList.UserId = _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Id;//!

                    comparsionList.ProductsToCompare = new List<ProductToCompare>();
                    comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.Add(new ProductToCompare { ProductId = productId });
                }
                else if (!comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.Any(z => z.ProductId == productId))
                {
                    comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.Add(new ProductToCompare { ProductId = productId });
                    comparsionList.CategoryId = _dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == productId).ProductCategories.FirstOrDefault().CategoryId;
                    comparsionList.SessionId = sessionId;
                    comparsionList.UserId = _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Id;
                }
            }                          

            await _dbContext.AddAsync(comparsionList);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new ProductComparsionVM
            {
                CategoryId = _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == comparsionList.CategoryId).Id,
                ProductsToCompare = comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.ToList()
            };
        }

public class ProductComparsionVM
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? ListId { get; set; }
    public List<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class ProductToCompareVM
{
    public ProductComparsion ProductComparsion { get; set; }
    public ProductVM Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where possible, post code, not images.

Comment: what is returned from `await _productRepo.AddProductToComparsionList(comparsion.ProductsToCompare.Select(z => z.ProductId).ToList(), comparsion.CategoryId, comparsion.ListId)` ?

Comment: Show the code of `ProductComparsionVM`, the way you're passing request data seems not correct.

Comment: @vasily.sib It returns ProductComparsionVM with fields `CategoryId` and `ProductsToCompare`. Added code

Comment: well, first of all `"ProductsToCompare": [0, 1]` is for `public List<int> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }`, not `List<ProductToCompare>`

Comment: @vasily.sib Thanks, now it works